# Error when importing big csv file into ELK by Logstash

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash

Each day I have big csv file (about 800M, more than 3.5 mil rows) needed to import into ElasticSearch by Logstash. Some days it works perfectly, but some days it imports not enough rows in csv file. I watch in log files in Logstash  (logstash-plain.log) and ElasticSearch and there is not any errors.
Information of ELK: ElasticSearch: 3 nodes, Logstash config:

```
input {
  file {
        path => "/home/importdata/pack_*.csv"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "csv_data.db"
  }
}

filter {
    if [path] =~ "pack_" {
        csv {
                separator => ";"
                skip_header => "true"
                columns => ["id","cif","global_id","cus_name","cus_dob","cus_address","cus_email","cus_phone","cus_branch","cus_acct_exec_code","cus_acct_exec_name","cus_branch_name","created_by","created_time","updated_by","updated_time","is_deleted","status","deleted_by","deleted_time","route","client_type","client_group"]              
            }
    }
    
    grok {
        match => [ "path", "/(?<filename>[^/]+).csv" ] 
    }
}

output {
 elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["http://ip1:9200","http://ip2:9200","http://ip3:9200"]
   index => "%{filename}"
 }
}
```

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: What do you have in the logs? Any warnings at least? Your index name will be extract from the `filename` field, if for some reason your `grok` filter fails, it will be stored in a literal index named `%{filename}`, did you check if you have this Index? Also, the files that you are reading that start with `pack_`, everything is lowercase, right?

Comment: @leandrojmp the index was created with the name is the prefix of the file name. But the index does not have all the documents corresponding to the rows in file. 
Log in the log file of Logstash:
[2022-08-08T07:05:08,724][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.codecs.plain][main][500e0e6a6141e5bf2655871570a947fc656461bbb7c8715f3faf52f3ca7048ef] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.

Comment: finally I found a solution to cover this issue: restart logstash daily before importing csv file. Now logstash can import 40mil rows without any errors. Hope can help others